# Custom numerical search in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, search, adobe, acrobat

I haven been trying to figure out how to write a greater than / less than custom search in Adobe Acrobat, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have consulted [this](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/custom-document-search-using-javascript), but it only seems to apply to text search.

I wrote this, but it didn't work:

```
search.query(> "1000","ActiveDoc");
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please provide some guidance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working, though I'd rather be able to search through the numbers (using the normal search function) versus having to open the javascript console for answers.

```
for (var p=0; p<this.numPages; p++) {
    for (var n=0; n<this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        var w = this.getPageNthWord(p, n);
        if  (w >= 10000) {
   console.println(w);
} else if  (w <= -10000) {
   console.println(w);
}

    }
}
```